# Disabling the ability for my iPhone to use my iPad as a Speaker for the Phone app

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, headphones

Since iOS11, when making a call using my iPhone Dialer app, instead of the speaker button being listed alone, when I click it, it has a context menu that offers Speaker or my iPad. I've never used this, and really have never wanted to use my iPad as the speakerphone for my Phone.

What's funny is that Googling for it shows very little written on this feature.

Any ideas on how to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your phone go to:
Settings > Phone > Calls on other devices.

Turn it off altogether, or just for your iPad.

Comment: Weird, so that means it's not going to ring there as well?

Comment: Right, there is no granularity to those settings per device, I.e. all phone features or no phone fetatures per device.